onEdit event triggers when a row is deleted
I am using onEdit trigger in Google Sheet to send an email notification based on cell changes with certain conditions.  That works fine, but the trigger also fires when a row is deleted and I get an error that the cells are undefined because of course the row was deleted.  Is there a way to catch that event within onEdit?  I know that I could use onChange as well, but would the onEdit event fire anyways?
Thanks for any tips.
I am not sure how to check for undefined values in the onEdit event within the e object.

Check again your project. An On Edit , simple an instalable, trigger Is not activated by a row deletion. If You need further help, please add a [mcve].

You could check if e.range is not undefined.
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range !== undefined){
    // Do Something
  }
}


That did not work.  I have switch onEdit to a simple trigger.  It did not fire when I deleted the row.  Then created installable onChange trigger to catch the row deletion event.  Thanks for your help though.
